# How to install Arch linux on pandaboard

Tags: arm, archlinux, pandaboard

Im having problems with the installation.
I tried this already , http://archlinuxarm.org/platforms/armv7/ti/pandaboard i don't know if im doing it correctly because when i connect it to the HDMI and the tv, nothing seems to work.

Comment: The problem is that PandaBoard !== PandaBoard-ES. I know, because I had that problem too. I only found working Ubuntu 12.04 installation for this board... nothing more.

Comment: Well, I have an Arch installation guide on my website: https://oneenterprisestech.github.io/ht1.html

It just goes over how to do the Arch Installation challenge, not how to install on a PandaBoard... It will help after you know how to boot the installation device.

Comment: I know this is very old, I just kind of wanted to comment on this...

Answer (score 1):

I recently got the same problem with my pandaboard ES. I can't say I have everything working now, but you can have a feedback of the boot with the DB9-RS232 port. You'll probably need to use an adaptator DB9/USB to open a serial connection at 115200 baud with the card (you can use the screen program to do so).